# Is is possible to use the Jenkins-Vagrant plugin when Jenkins is running inside a VM?

Tags: jenkins, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm trying to use the Jenkins-vagrant plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Vagrant-plugin) to boot up vagrant boxes from within Jenkins. However, Jenkins itself is running on a VM (itself a vagrant box) rather than directly on Windows, which is where VirtualBox is installed. As such, when Jenkins tries to run vagrant up I get "Vagrant could not detect VirtualBox! Make sure VirtualBox is properly installed." on the Jenkins console. How can I tell Jenkins to use the VirtualBox executable on my host machine? Some kind of port forwarding maybe?